# How to get window size in swift (including iPad split screen)

Tags: ios, swift, screen, cgrect

I want to get the window bounds as `CGRect` object.
This is my current code:

```
let screenSize : CGRect = self.view.window?.frame
```

I found this code on the internet, **but sometimes `screenSize` is nil.**
Is there any other option?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I've found the answer

```
let screenSize : CGRect = self.view.frame
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.filter({ $0.isKeyWindow }).first {
   let screenFrame = window.frame
}
```

You can get the sizes from the `screenFrame`

Answer (score 1):

`UIView` has a property called `window`, which is called `nil` until the view is added to the window. Get the `frame` when the `window` property is not `nil`. So, in the experiment below, the `view.window` value is not `nil` only when entering `viewWillLayoutSubviews`.

https://eunjin3786.tistory.com/96

Sorry, I couldn't find a good example in English. In this experiment, the author marked the blue title at the time when `view.window` was not `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

iOS 15 deprecated the aforementioned solutions. Here's a new syntax that should be up to date, safe and actually work on split screen iPad.

```swift
let windowSize = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
                .compactMap({ scene -> UIWindow? in
                    (scene as? UIWindowScene)?.keyWindow
                })
                .first?
                .frame
                .size
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get the height and width separately by typing:

```
let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
let screenWidth = screenSize.width
let screenHeight = screenSize.height
```

Comment: No, this is not my issue. I want to get the **window** frame (so it will be affected from the iPad split view)